# Linear interpolation in datatable C# - determining datatypes

Tags: c#, datatable, linear-interpolation

I am looking to build a method for interpolating data from a datatable and would like to know suggestions on the most efficient way of doing this. I have something like this started:

```
List<double> freqlist, Rlist, Llist, Qlist;

foreach (DataRow row in tdt.Table.Rows) //tdt contains my datatable
        {
            freqlist.Add(row.Field<double>("FREQ"));
            Rlist.Add(row.Field<double>("R"));
            Llist.Add(row.Field<double>("L"));
            Qlist.Add(row.Field<double>("Q"));
        }
```

After pulling the data into several lists, I use a linear interpolation method that works on sorted lists, which is currently working, but only if I know the datatypes beforehand (currently using doubles).

*I am getting stuck here:* I would like this method to be able to determine the data types from the datatable **beforehand** (from the column?) and use that in the row.Field<> extension for list.Add.

I had no luck using a type / typecode variable (is this even possible?) in the row.Field<> by something like this:

```
System.Type tc = System.Type.GetType(tdt.Table.Columns["R"].DataType.ToString());
    freqlist.Add(row.Field <tc> ("FREQ"));
```

---

Does anyone know another way to use the result of a type check?

Also, is there a better way to interpolate on the table itself without lists?

Answer (score 0):

Really, to sort you just need classes that implement `IComparable`.

So what if, instead of `Field<double>`, you used `Field<IComparable>`? A `double` implements IComparable. So does short, int, etc.

Comment: OK, giving this a try now. Do I need to make a brand new class, or just use 'IComparable' in place of 'double'?

Comment: a double, int, short, etc... they all *are* an IComparable. But I've just now realized an error in my suggest. You'd now have a list of things you can't get the value of, but just compare two of them. So you couldn't, say print the list out later.